# Why are 2 lines rendered with this code (drawRect)?

Tags: objective-c, macos, graphics, drawrect

I was wondering why my window looks like this:
[image: 2 lines]

When I resize the window, one line keeps stretching while the other one keeps statically sized and skewed.

[image: As you can see, one of the lines keeps to the edges.]

The strange part is, that I record the height and width of the window whenever `drawRect` is called.

At the start of the application, the drawRect method gets called 4 times.
[image: strange]

I looked at this and realized it wasn't the actual size, and moved the window size a bit and got **real** results. What's strange, is how it jumped so fast.

[image]

The strange part is how the "ghost" line is still there, *I have no idea which one is the ghost!* Why? I changed the color of the line which is displayed... and:

[image]

The one which is statically displayed is the one which is "generated" using my code each drawRect.

The code I am using for my drawRect:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    NSLog(@"%f, %f", dirtyRect.size.height, dirtyRect.size.width);
    NSBezierPath *line = [NSBezierPath bezierPath];
    [line moveToPoint:NSMakePoint(NSMaxX([self bounds]), NSMaxY([self   bounds]))];
    //Sorry about formatting; SO doesn't make it easy to format.
    [line lineToPoint:NSMakePoint(NSMinX([self bounds]), NSMinY([self bounds]))];
    [line setLineWidth:_lwith]; /// Make it easy to see
    [_lineColor set]; /// Make future drawing the color of lineColor.

    [line stroke];
}
```

I am asking for a bit of explanation, or just anything that will help! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Self answered**

*What did I do?*: I had my subclass of NSView inside of another NSView in the storyboard; the child NSView was statically kept at a certain size, while the NSView (parent/window) was moving around freely. Keep in mind, I had my instance of the child NSView saved in my ViewController. 
My NSView was displaying a line no matter what, and it only changed color if I had the instance of itself.

Make sure you have your storyboard all checked, mine looks like this now:
[image]

Notice how neat it is to have only one "graph" view ;)